# try_files dynamic content type

Tags: nginx

I was wondering how I could serve different content type for each file.
For example I have following nginx configuration:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name site.com;

    location ~ ^/(.*) {
        root /home/site/;
        try_files $uri
            $uri.png
            $uri.bin
            =404;
        }
}
```

So for example any `$uri.png` will have `image/png` content type header and `$uri.bin` will have `application/octet-stream`.

Problem: I don't know how to determine `file` which `try_files` has picked.
I have lua module set up and working just in case it will be needed.

Have anyone else tried something like this?

Comment: Could you clarify what do you want?  Probably you need `types` directive, but I'm not sure.

Comment: I need that appropriate content type header would be sent to user. `types` is included in main `nginx.conf`

Comment: So what the problem then? With default types you'll get image/png for `$uri.png` and `application/octet-stream` for `$uri.bin`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Assuming I've understood what you are after, this works for me:

```
if ($request_uri ~* \.png$) {
    more_set_headers "Content-type: image/png";
}
if ($request_uri ~* \.(jpg|jpeg)$) {
    more_set_headers "Content-type: image/jpeg";
}
if ($request_uri ~* \.gif$) {
    more_set_headers "Content-type: image/gif";
}
```

Requires a non-standard module, unless nginx has changed recently to allow the standard add_header function to overwrite Content-type: http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpHeadersMoreModule

If you want to go in reverse (i.e. original URI contains no extension and filesystem does), try replacing $request_uri with $uri, and the order of before/after try_files may matter